# Is it possible to automatically get a Bold \subref

Tags: subcaption

I am using the `subcaption` package to render my images. 
In the caption I refer to the subfigure using `\subref`.

Due to requirements I am required to refer to the subfigures by a boldface letter in parentheses i.e. **(a)**.

I currently use

```
\textbf{\subref{fig:figurelabel}}.
```

I managed to add the parentheses by adding the option `subrefformat=parens` to my preamble:

```
\usepackage[position=t,singlelinecheck=off]{subcaption}
\captionsetup{subrefformat=parens}
```

Is there I could add that also makes this boldfaced?

Kind regards,

Adriaan

Comment: Have you tried the option `labelfont=bf` when loading the `subcaption` package? I'm assuming that you would want "a" to be typeset in bold both in the caption and in the cross-reference.

Comment: I tried the labelfont =bf option. This does not seem to change anything. As the labels themselves were already bold, only when referencing they were not boldfaced. The solution Torbjorn works tough.

Comment: As you hadn't posted a complete example, I couldn't know that you were already making the caption label **bold**. When in doubt, post a complete example that shows all code that's relevant for the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define your own `subrefformat`:

```
\DeclareCaptionLabelFormat{bold}{\textbf{(#2)}}
\captionsetup{subrefformat=bold}
```

Complete example:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[position=t,singlelinecheck=off]{subcaption}
\DeclareCaptionLabelFormat{bold}{\textbf{(#2)}}
\captionsetup{subrefformat=bold}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{subfigure}{5cm}
\centering
\caption{sub}\label{sub}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{main}
\end{figure}

\subref{sub}
\end{document}
```